# $A$ is a separating class if it is a $\pi$-system generating the sigma-field $B(S)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(S,d)$ be metric space and $B(S)$ be Borel sigma algebra.

Define a subclass $A$ of $B(S)$ to be a separating class if
two probability measures that agree on $A$ necessarily agree also on the
whole of $B(S)$: The values of $P(A)$ for $A$ in $A$ are enough to separate $P$ from
all the other probability measures on $S$.

In the book I am currently reading "Convergence of probability measures" by Patrick Billingsley it is said that $A$ is
a separating class if it is a $\pi$-system generating the sigma-field $B(S)$.

I don't know how to prove it.

My idea was to take any set in $B(S)$ and since it  is generated by this separating class it can be represented by some union/intersection of sets from there(?) But I don't know whether this union/intersection has to be countable. If yes then $P$ as a measure is countably additive and the result would follow, but i wouln't even use that is is $\pi$-system.

So my guess the representation is not necessarily countable and it has to be done differently.

As an example, tuples of closed intervals generate Borel sigma algebra in $R^n$, and is a $\pi$-system so they constitute separating class.

I can't prove it even using this specific example.

Comment: This is the so called $\pi-\lambda$ Theorem. See Theorem 1.4 in "Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions".

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is a $\pi$-system with $\sigma(A) = B(S)$. Suppose $P$ and $Q$ are probability measures that agree on $A$. Let $\mathcal{C} = \{E \in B(S) : P(E) = Q(E)\}$. It is easy to show that $\Omega \in \mathcal{C}$, $E \in \mathcal{C} \implies E^c \in \mathcal{C}$, and $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under countable disjoint unions. Thus $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\lambda$-system. Since $A \subset \mathcal{C}$, we get $\lambda(A) \subset \mathcal{C}$. The $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem says $\lambda(A) = \sigma(A)$ when $A$ is a $\pi$-system, so we obtain $\sigma(A) = B(S) \subset \mathcal{C}$.